# How to get attribute value from jsonb in postgresql using Panache and Hibernate?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I use quarkus-spring-data-jpa extension, but since native queries are not supported, I can't execute a query similar to this `select * from test_table where test_json->>'FirstValue' = :value`. I have not found how to do this using only JPQL. How can I make such a request using Hibernate and Panache ?

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/